# Make a no-window entry widget with perl Gtk2

Tags: perl, widget, gtk2

I would like to get an entry widget with no background (the same background as the main window, as in the second image from http://www.lanedo.com/~carlos/gtk3-doc/chap-drawing-model.html#figure-windowed-label). For label widget, this is the case as these are no-window widgets. Can we do the same from entry widgets?

Please suggest a way to get it from the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use Gtk2 -init;

my $dialog = Gtk2::Dialog->new ('Message', undef,
                'destroy-with-parent',
                'gtk-ok' => 'none');
my $label = Gtk2::Label->new ('Label text with no window: background of main window');
$dialog->get_content_area ()->add ($label);
my $entry = Gtk2::Entry->new();
$entry->set_text('Entry text, white background');
$dialog->get_content_area ()->add ($entry);
$dialog->show_all;
$dialog->signal_connect (response => sub { $_[0]->destroy });
$dialog->run;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying no "frame" or "border"

Comment: adding `$entry->set_has_frame(0);$entry->set_inner_border(undef);` does not change the background - only the entry outline.

Comment: set background? `$entry->modify_bg(undef,undef);`

Comment: The first argument to `modify_bg` must be a `GtkStateType` value. However, this does not change anything whatever the first argument you use (`normal`, `active`, `prelight`,...)